# How do I show that the set of all points that are less than $\varepsilon$ away from a set is open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $A \subset \mathbb R$, we have the distance between a point in $\mathbb R$ and $A$ as

$$d(x,A)=\inf\{|x-a| \mid a \in A\}.$$

**For $\varepsilon>0$, if we define $A(\varepsilon) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid d(x,A) < \varepsilon \}$, how do we show this set is open?**

---

I know that $A \subset A(\varepsilon)$ since for any point in $a \in A$ we will have $d(a, A)=0 < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon >0$.

I can see that $A(\varepsilon)$ is sort of like a neighborhood of the set $A$ but I am having trouble formalizing this.

Comment: What's your definition of "open"? Is it "every point is contained in an open ball"?

Comment: Yes. A set $X$ is open if for every $x \in X$, there exists a neighborhood of $x$ contained entirely in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set S in metric space is open if for any $x \in S$, there is $\delta>0$(this $\delta$ depends of $x$) such that $B_{\delta}(x) \subset S$.

Take $x \in A(\epsilon)$. In this case we choose $\delta = \epsilon - d(x,A)$.

Take $y \in B_{\delta}(x)$. Then we have $d(y,A) \leq d(y,x) + d(x,A)< \epsilon - d(x,A) + d(x,A)$.

Then $A(\epsilon)$ is open.

Comment: The proof ends after "$\delta = \epsilon - d(x,A)$", correct? The part after this just guarantees that $B_{\delta}(x) \subset S$?

Comment: No, for the proof is very important guarantes that $y \in A(\epsilon)$ and, consequently, $B_{\delta} \subset A(\epsilon)$. Our definition of open set needs this part.

Comment: Will $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0} A(\epsilon)$ be open?

Comment: No. It will be $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{A}$ is closed and not open. Why? You can look the complement of this intersection. If $x$ is complement, then exists $\epsilon_{0}$ such that $d(x,A)>\epsilon$, now apply almost same idea.

Comment: And if complement of set is open, the set is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd start by taking an arbitrary $x\in A(\varepsilon).$ Since $d(x,A)<\varepsilon,$ then there is some $a\in A$ such that $|x-a|<\varepsilon.$ (Can you see why?) Thus, for any $x\in A(\varepsilon),$ we have that $$x\in\bigcup_{a\in A}(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon).\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ On the other hand, given an arbitrary $x$ as in $(\heartsuit),$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $|x-a|<\varepsilon,$ so $d(x,A)<\varepsilon.$ (Do you see why?) Thus, $x\in A(\varepsilon).$

By double inclusion, $$A(\varepsilon)=\bigcup_{a\in A}(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon),$$ so as a union of open intervals, $A(\varepsilon)$ is open. (Can you justify this?)

Comment: Will $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0} A(\epsilon)$ be open?

Comment: It will not, in general--rather, it will be the closure of $A,$ which is closed. In particular, it will be open if and only if either (1) $A$ is empty or (2) $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

If you know that a function is continous if and only if preimages of open sets are open, you can just prove that $d(x,A)$ is continous, and then observe that if $f(x) = d(x,A)$,

$$
A(\epsilon) = f^{-1}(-\infty, \epsilon)
$$

which is in fact the preimage via a continous function of the open set $(-\infty, \epsilon)$.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically one can guess that for any $b\in A(\varepsilon)$, the ball of radius **$\frac{\varepsilon -d(b,A)}{2}$** and centered at $b$ will lie inside $A(\varepsilon)$. Of course you need to prove it mathematically.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment than an answer.